# sunburst.R total frequency count is incorrect

Tags: r

I am plotting a sunburst donut and I cannot figure out why the total is incorrect.

```
library(sunburstR)
reports <- data.frame(
    sequence = c("SVP-VP-Dir-end","SVP-VP-Dir-end","SVP-VP-Dir-end","SVP-VP-Dir-end","SVP-No VP-Dir-end","SVP-No VP-Dir-end","SVP-No VP-Dir-end"),                          
    freq = as.numeric(c("167","60","51","32","5","1","1")))

sunburst(reports, count = TRUE)
```

It is supposed to be 100% 317 of 317 . Anyone know how to fix this? There is not much documentation on this great package.

Also, I would like it to have a default value in the center of donut.

[image]

If there is another way to create an interactive donut using R, please let me know.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the default function generating the message in the center of the donut rounds the total value to the nearest ten.

But you can customize this function using the `explanation` argument of `sunburst`. Oddly, the customized function (in javascript) must be provided as a string.

Try the following function:

```
custom.message = "function (d) {
  root = d;
  while (root.parent) {
    root = root.parent
  }
  p = (100*d.value/root.value).toPrecision(3);
  msg = p+' %<br/>'+d.value+' of '+root.value;
  return msg;
}"
```

Now:

```
sunburst(reports, explanation = custom.message )
```

will generate the donut displaying exact total values. The `count` argument is no longer needed, as it is used by the default explanation function.

The value returned by `custom.message` is html code. As you can see, I've just inserted a line break (`<br/>`). You can modify the `msg` return value to further customize the look and feel.

Comment: fjarino, your solution works. I had resorted to the following solution `sunburst(reports, explanation = "function(d){return d.value}")`.  However, your is a better solution. Thank you